# Interceptor not intercepting http requests (Angular 6)

Tags: angular

I'm in the proces of adding an interceptor to my angular 6 project. To make calls to my API, I need to add a bearer token to all calls. Unfortunately the interceptor does not seem to be called. My code:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>,
              next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        //Retrieve accesstoken from local storage
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");

        //Check if accesToken exists, else send request without bearer token
        if (accessToken) {
            const cloned = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set("Authorization",
                    "Bearer " + accessToken)
            });

            console.log('Token added to HTTP request');

            return next.handle(cloned);
        }
        else {
            //No token; proceed request without bearer token
            console.log('No token added to HTTP request');
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you provide HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in your app.module?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to do that. Seems to be fixed now. If you post it as an answer ill mark it as solved.

Comment: This blog may be used  https://laxmanchavda.blogspot.com/2018/10/intercept-all-http-request-in-angular.html

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You use the right way to intercept.

For people who use interceptor, you need to do 2 modifications :

**Interceptor in service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse }
  from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).do(evt => {
      if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
        console.log('---> status:', evt.status);
        console.log('---> filter:', req.params.get('filter'));
      }
    });

  }
}
```

**Provide HTTP_INTERCEPTOR**

```js
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
(...)
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
```

[Read this article for more details](https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/). It's pretty good

Comment: Keep in mind that rxjs has changed a lot. do operator now is called tap and needs to be used within a pipe() https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: This is really quite out of date now

Answer (score 139):

In my case interceptor wasn't getting involved for service calls because I had imported `HttpClientModule` multiple times, for different modules.

Later I found that `HttpClientModule` must be imported only once. [Doc ref](https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-installing-the-module)

Comment: thanks !!  been trying to resolve this issue for 2 days straight...  it was multiple imports of HttpClientModule

Comment: Spot on! Make sure that you do not import it twice or more. Check your shared module as well, in case you import any in your App Module. That was the issue for me, at least :)

Comment: This can also happen if the Service for which you want to intercept requests is (unnecessarily) added to the provided attribute of some (sub)module. Removing it from the list of provided services made the HttpInterceptor work again.

Comment: Wow!! thank's Praveen!

Answer (score 9):

If you have a providers array for a module then you have to define the HTTP_INTERCEPTORS too for that module then only it will intercept the requests under that module.

e.g:

```
providers: [ 
// singleton services
PasswordVerifyService,
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppInterceptor, multi: true },
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptorService, multi: true }
]
```

Comment: Now what is the point of the angular-cli if it doesn't do this work for us 

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same behavior with my standalone component (interceptors not intercepting my http requests).

If you use **standalone components** instead of importing HttpClientModule in your Module, note that you have to add `withInterceptorsFromDi()` in your `provideHttpClient(...)` to make your interceptors work! Or use the new way of functional interceptors via `withInterceptors`.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76028543) for more details.

Comment: To make it more clear in your `providers` (found in `app.config.ts`) it should look like this `provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())`. 

I had been dealing with this problem for a month since I only had `provideHttpClient(...)`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to import both `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule` in same module.

Comment: if you add `HttpClientModule` & `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` in your parent module then you'll not need to import these two in your sub-modules.

Comment: Same for me. Does it mean I can't add interceptors only for some child modules?

Answer (score 3):

In my case i had a post method like this:

```
this.http.post<any>(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
            let token: any = response.token;
            if (token) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', 'value' }));                
                return response; 
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }),
        catchError((error:any) => {return observableThrowError(error.json().error || 'Server error')})
      );
```

Because the `map` method could return `null` the interceptor stopped intercepting the requests made with this post method call. Don't ask me why this is so, but as soon as i replace `null` with say `response` everything started working again.

Comment: This helped me figured out how to fix my issue.. In my case, once the HTTP request fails, the subsequent request doesn't get intercepted. by returning null in catchError fixed mine

Answer (score 2):

Check your module & sub-module files, If you have imported the interceptor in a sub-module, then move it to the root module and it should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31842694)

Answer (score 2):

In my case the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) was not used to do the requests.

Instead **[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) has been used directly** and that is not intercepted by angular.

Changed `fetch(...)` to `http.get(...)` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally had my service proivded `providers  : [ ApplicationService ]` in my component when it wasn't supposed to be as I had it defined using `providedIn: 'root'`

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that dependencies for the interceptor are also provided in the module. ProvidedIn:'root' for the interceptor dependency services did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I am working with modules, I had to import the child module **(AuthModule)** in **app.module.ts**. I was just missing that.

**imports: [
HttpClientModule,
AppRoutingModule,
AuthModule
]**