# When reload the page error 401 is thrown, i'm using Angular 5

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot and JWT to generate the authentication token, when I access the page by browsing the links, the error does not occur, but when I reload the page, the 401 error occurs, below are the processes

Process ok:

```
GENERAL:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/corridas/aposta?idUsuario=10&size=5&page=0&sort=id,desc
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 03:02:54 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request Headers:
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c3VhcmlvNEB0ZXN0ZS5jb20uYnIiLCJjcmVhdGVkIjoxNjAzOTM3ODY2NTMyLCJleHAiOjE2MDQ1NDI2NjZ9.C-kbadiNZpcKrFgX7kiymJQfigmHe9ZKIGLlMYxYiZaLBbf0P-JY271hV0Tx2toV3I9ZemyGVwgaAp2tDQNF-A
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: usuario=Fantasma; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c3VhcmlvNEB0ZXN0ZS5jb20uYnIiLCJjcmVhdGVkIjoxNjAzOTM3ODY2NTMyLCJleHAiOjE2MDQ1NDI2NjZ9.C-kbadiNZpcKrFgX7kiymJQfigmHe9ZKIGLlMYxYiZaLBbf0P-JY271hV0Tx2toV3I9ZemyGVwgaAp2tDQNF-A;
Host: localhost:8080
Referer: http://localhost:8080/corridas/torcida
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Process 401 after reload page

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/corridas/aposta?idUsuario=10&size=5&page=0&sort=id,desc
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: pt-BR
Content-Length: 301
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 29 Oct 2020 03:03:54 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Request Headers:
Accept:     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: usuario=Fantasma; token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c3VhcmlvNEB0ZXN0ZS5jb20uYnIiLCJjcmVhdGVkIjoxNjAzOTM3ODY2NTMyLCJleHAiOjE2MDQ1NDI2NjZ9.C-kbadiNZpcKrFgX7kiymJQfigmHe9ZKIGLlMYxYiZaLBbf0P-JY271hV0Tx2toV3I9ZemyGVwgaAp2tDQNF-A;
Host: localhost:8080
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like     Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Here the angular interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>  {
    let authRequest: any;
    if (this.shared.isLoggedIn()){
        authRequest = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization': this.shared.buscaChaveUsuario()
            }
        });
        return next.handle(authRequest);
    } else {
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

When I access the pages through the website links the interceptor is always called, when I reload the page the interceptor is not called, I believe that the error must be precisely at this point, it is possible to see that in the first process I am passing the token through the 'Authorization' header , in the second process, where the 401 error is launched, the 'Authorization' header is not passed because the interceptor is not called, in short, does anyone have any clue as to the reason for this error?

Comment: where and how do you add bind the interceptor in your app?

Comment: @Crocsx Hello Crocsx, sorry for the delay in responding, but come on, the interceptor is being used  in the provider of the app.module, below is how it is called.
.
.
`code
providers:
[SharedService,
AuthGuard,
{
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: AuthInterceptor,
  multi: true
}, `

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned in question that interceptor is not getting called but I think interceptor is getting called each time instead the below part of code is creating issue.

```
if (this.shared.isLoggedIn()){
    authRequest = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            'Authorization': this.shared.buscaChaveUsuario()
        }
    });
    return next.handle(authRequest);
```

}

As `isLoggedIn()` and `buscaChaveUsuario()` functions are taking values from some variables that is present in your application i.e Angular Project. So when we you refresh the page application will reload and those variable will be cleared and when the call will come to interceptor again values will not be present there and that's why on reload 'Authorization' header is not going.

One quick solution that you can try is to put these values in localStorage of the browser so that it will not be cleared on reload and remove the values from localStorage when the user logs out.

Comment: @Manoj So, sorry for the delay in responding, I did a test here, after logging I added the token to the local storage: 
.
`localStorage.setItem('token', this.shared.token); `
.
And on the Interceptor, I'm taking the localStorage value to pass as the 'Authorization' parameter,
.
`Authorization': localStorage.getItem ('token') `

but the error continues, when I enter a page browsing the links everything works, if I update or try to access a direct page.

When debugging the code the interceptor is called only when I browse the links, when I update the page the interceptor is not called.

Comment: @RonaldCalazans Can you verify that you are importing HttpClientModule only once as specified in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860293/interceptor-not-intercepting-http-requests-angular-6/50860940

Comment: Hello @AJcodes, so, after reading the post that recommended me, I took a look at my code, I'm using only an "HttpClientModule" ... the page reload was working, at some point in the development this function broke, I implemented an AuthGuard to send access without authentication to the login page, and it was working, the system as it is now broke AuthGuard, it doesn't work anymore ... as I reported in the main post when I try to reload the page or try to access a page through direct link (example: localhost: 8080 / runnings / events) gives error 401

Comment: I found the point of the error, but I didn't find the solution hehe ... I'm packing the frontend and backend in the same .war, I did a test, I went up the frontend on port 4200 and the backend on port 8080, this way I can reload the page, if I run the frontend from .war I can't reload the page, any tips?

Answer (score -1):

The are several ways to handling this.

Practical example:
I would advice that the first time that you successfully log in in your site, you can store the jwt token in a the browser storage.

I.E the user provide some valid credentials in `mysite.com/login`, if the credentials are fine, your site will store those credentials on the browser storage and lets suppose that the default behavior of the web is that on a successfull login, it should redirect the user to mysite.com/home.

Now, you can protect your mysite.com/home route with an `Angular Guard` that can essentially check if there is a valid, non expired token on the session storage. If there is not any, return false on the guard and redirect to a forbidden page.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, so thanks for the reply :), the behavior of the system is exactly what you proposed: The person logs in, and is directed to the 'home', if I navigate by clicking on the buttons the pages open, but if i reload the page always gives error 401, i cannot reload any page, i also implemented an AuthGuard to prevent unauthorized access if the person is not logged in.