# HTTP Interceptor not sending firebase auth token

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angular-httpclient

I have a go web server to which I am sending requests from my application. I have written an HTTP interceptor in order to attach the auth token given by firebase so I can validate it on my go web server. For some reason, the interceptor doesn't appear to be changing the headers of the request to attach the auth token.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
            return from(this.auth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()).pipe(switchMap(token => {
                if(token){
                    const authReq = req.clone({
                        setHeaders: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                             Authorization: token,
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                        }
                    });
                    return next.handle(authReq);
                }
                return next.handle(req);
                })
            );
        return next.handle(req);
    }
```

This within a service called AuthHandler which implements HTTPInterceptor. Any help would be appreciated! I am on angularfire version 5.4 and angular9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my problem wasn't with firebase but rather setting up the interceptor. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860293/interceptor-not-intercepting-http-requests-angular-6) is very useful. Essentially you have to include the service class in the providers section of the app module.

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
(...)
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
```