# keycloak-angular with AngularElements and Standalone Component (no Authorization Header added to requests)

Tags: angular, keycloak, angular-elements, angular-standalone-components, keycloak-angular

I have an angular app (and a nestjs backend) and I try to handle  user login with the help of keycloak. As the buzzword rich question title states I have kind of a "weird" architecture.

- I want to create a `custom element` with the help of angular (works)
- I thought I don't need an own module for the component I build, so it is a `standalone component` (works)
- I use `keycloak-angular` in main.ts to do the login (works, I get a token, username, roles,...)
- I use the `HttpClient` for the requests of that component (custom element) to its backend (requests do work, but the bearer token is not added)

According to the [readme of keycloak-angular](https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular#httpclient-interceptor):

> "By default, all HttpClient requests will add the Authorization
> header"

Also when I add a `shouldAddToken` function to the `KeycloakOptions` that I set in the `keycloakService.init` method, this function is never called.

I thought, maybe the HttpClient in the component is another instance than the one in main.ts but I checked it and it is the same instance. (have set `(httpService as any).mytest = 1;` in main.ts and the httpService in the component had that parameter).

Any idea what I could miss?

**The relevant code in main.ts**

```
(async () => {

    // inspired by https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/angular-elements-web-components-with-standalone-components/
    const app = await createApplication({
        providers: [
            provideHttpClient(),
            KeycloakService,
            {
                // I guess this should not be necessary, but I tryed anyway
                provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
                useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
                multi: true,
                deps: [KeycloakService]
            },
        ],
    });


    try {
        await initializeKeycloak(app);
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.error('Seems like there was a problem with the login', err);
        return;
    }

    // register my root component as CustomElement
    customElements.define(
        'my-component',
        createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: app.injector })
    );

})();
```

- 

```
async function initializeKeycloak(app: ApplicationRef) {
    
    const keycloakService = app.injector.get(KeycloakService);
                
    return keycloakService.init({
        
        // keycloak address and client data coming from environment file
        config: environment.keycloak.config,

        /* without this getUsername() returns the Error "User not logged in or user profile was not loaded." */
        loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,

        initOptions: {
            enableLogging: true,
            onLoad: 'login-required',
            // someone on the web had the same problem (no auth header) and fixed it with this (not sure if this is relevant, it does not help in my case)
            silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
                window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
        },
        shouldAddToken: (request) => {
            // is never logged
            console.log('XXXXXXXXXXX addToken?', request);
            return true;
        }
        
    }).then(async loggedIn =>  {
        if (loggedIn) {
            
            // returns sane data
            console.log("loggedIn: ", {
                loggedIn,
                username: keycloakService.getUsername(),
                roles: keycloakService.getUserRoles().join(', '),
                jwt: jwt_decode(await keycloakService.getToken())
            });
            
            // returns true
            console.log("keycloakService.enableBearerInterceptor", keycloakService.enableBearerInterceptor);

        } else {
            console.log(`keycloak.init returned ` + loggedIn);
        }
        
        return loggedIn;
    });
}
```

---

**Update**

Two things I am not sure about and that could cause the Keycloak Interceptor to not add the bearer token:

**Maybe they are not added if the domain is different?**

- my keycloak is at http://test.local:8080
- my angular app at http://localhost:4200
- my backend app at http://localhost:3333

**Maybe the HttpInterceptor needs to be added for every module that does http request?!**
Already tried to add the following (without success) to one of the modules that is imported by my AppModule and does requests via the HttpClient.

```
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,  
    multi: true, 
    ...
```

The HttpClient is the same instance everywhere (as written earlier).

Comment: I would try to reduce the complexity.

Make it work without a custom element and standalone component.
Then try to add these features again.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I'd also like to integrate Keycloak with standalone components. Login basically works but my "AuthGuard" seems to create a new KeycloakService instance so the routing fails as the requests appear unauthenticated. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

As I use a standalone component I can't add the HttpClientModule to the imports array of the AppModule. **The new way of doing this** is the method
`provideHttpClient`.

Instead of adding constructs like this to your providers array

```
{
   // I guess this should not be necessary, but I tryed anyway
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
   multi: true,
   deps: [KeycloakService]
},
```

you can add the new "functional interceptors" to the `provideHttpClient` like so

```
provideHttpClient(
    withInterceptors([ requestInterceptor ]) 
)
```

where requestInterceptor is a simple function instead of a service

```
function requestInterceptor(
    req: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandlerFn
): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    ...
}
```

You can also add "**Legacy Interceptors**" like before BUT you have to tell the new API to search and inject them in your providers via **`withInterceptorsFromDi()`**. And that's what was missing in my code.

Looks like this now

```
const app = await createApplication({
    providers: [
        ...,
        provideHttpClient(
            withInterceptors([
                // just testing the new way of intercepting
                requestInterceptor
            ]),
            withInterceptorsFromDi()
        ),
        KeycloakAngularModule,
        KeycloakService,
        KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: KeycloakBearerInterceptor,
            multi: true,
            deps: [KeycloakService]
        },
        {
            // testing own legacy interceptor
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: LoggingInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
    ],
});
```

All 3 interceptors work.

[This article](https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/the-refurbished-httpclient-in-angular-15-standalone-apis-and-functional-interceptors/) was my knight in shining armor

Comment: Can you share the full code please?

Comment: @MarcGuillem Here is a response featuring a working example, including Angular 17 standalone and Keycloak 23
https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/384#issuecomment-1895845160