# Angular Standalone with Keycloak integration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, keycloak

I'm working on an ionic-angular (Angular 17 and Ionic/Angular 7) app with standalone components and like to integrate with Keycloak (keycloak-angular 15.0.0 and keycloak-js 22.0.5). I've done a few working applications with Angular and Keycloak before but all based on NgModule. I have an `AccountService` that handles all the Keycloak interactions and an `AuthGuard` to protect access to certain components. Both are referring to the `KeycloakService` and it seems like it gets initialized twice.

Here's the relevant code pieces. The app should support multiple tenants so I have to re-initialize Keycloak with the required realm upon login.

main.ts

```
  const providers = [
    provideIonicAngular(),
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: IonicRouteStrategy
    },
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    KeycloakService,
    Storage,
  ];

  const app = await bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
    providers: providers,
  });

  try {
    await initKeycloak(app.injector.get(KeycloakService), environment.realm);
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

account.service.ts

```
  constructor(
    private readonly keycloakService: KeycloakService, ...) {}

  ...
  login(email: string, realm: string): void {
    const loginOptions: KeycloakLoginOptions = {
      loginHint: email,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/tabs',
    };
    this.onInitKeycloak(realm);
    this.keycloakService.login(loginOptions).then(() => this.afterInitKeycloak());
  }
  ...

export function initKeycloak(keycloakService: KeycloakService, realm: string) {
  return keycloakService.init({
    config: {
      url: environment!.authUrl,
      realm: window.localStorage.getItem(SessionStateService.tenantKey) || realm,
      clientId: environment!.clientId
    },
    initOptions: {
      enableLogging: !environment!.production,
      onLoad: 'check-sso',
      silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/assets/silent-check-sso.html`,
    },
    enableBearerInterceptor: true,
    bearerExcludedUrls: ['/assets', '/styles', '/api'],
    loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
    shouldAddToken: (request: any) => true
  });
}
```

auth.guard.ts

```
  constructor(
    protected override readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloakService: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloakService);
  }
  ...
  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login').then();
    }
    return this.authenticated;
```

The login itself seems to work but then the redirect to the requested (protected) component does not work because `AuthGuard.isAccessAllowed` returns `false`. Could it be that the `KeycloakService` injected in `AuthGuard` is not the same instance as in `AccountService`?

I have checked other questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600996/how-to-import-keycloak-module-using-standalone-components-and-without-ngmodule) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945094/keycloak-angular-with-angularelements-and-standalone-component-no-authorization) without success so far. I have even tried to switch back to the NgModule approach but then I have a different issue that `<app-root>` remains empty and `AppComponent` does not render. Any hints appreciated, it's driving me nuts.