# angular interceptor doesnt work for <img [src]="url" *ngIf="!isimageloading">

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-httpclient-interceptors

```
 <img [src]="url" *ngIf="!isimageloading">
```

in a form with submit in html

in component

```
fetchImage(form:NgForm)
  {
    this.url="http://localhost:3000/getimage/"+this.groupby+"/"+this.aggregate+"("+this.column+")";
    this.isimageloading = false;
   

  }
```

only one module-app module.only 2 http client imports one in httpservice and one in appcomponent.

tried:[Interceptor not intercepting http requests (Angular 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860293/interceptor-not-intercepting-http-requests-angular-6)
expecting : to intercept request

Comment: How did you setup your interceptor ?

Comment: your code looks like it just sets a string and then flips the boolean to false, but that has nothing to do with whether the image is actually loaded or not, as the title of your question seems to imply. Are you trying to get the image to pre-load and only show when it is done loading? If that's the case, you might want to try the following instead:

<img #imgElement [src]="url" [hidden]="!imgElement.complete">  

I haven't confirmed that this works but so long as change detection picks up on imgElement.complete, it should.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{


  y:any;
  constructor(private authService:AuthService) { }
  intercept(req,next)
  {
 
    let tokenizedReq=req.clone({
      setHeaders:{
        Authorization:`Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}` 
      }
    }
      )
      
      this.y= next.handle(tokenizedReq)
      console.log(this.y)
      console.log("hi")
      return this.y;



  }

}.it works for login/register posts requests but not for the above get requests